# How do I solve $Cov(X-Y,X-Y)$?

Tags: probability, covariance

I am revisiting my covariance rules so that I can have a better understanding of how does covariance of brownian motion works.
Basically what I did was.

$Cov(X-Y,X-Y) = Cov(X,X) +2Cov(X,-Y)+Cov(-Y,-Y)=Cov(X,X)-2Cov(X,Y) +Cov(-Y,-Y)=Var(X) +Var(Y)-2Cov(X,Y)$.

However this doesn't match,
$Cov(X-Y,X-Y) = Var(X-Y) = Var(X)+Var(Y)$.
Can Some one explain what I did wrong.
On another note: I'm finding stochastic processes really difficult compared to like say inference, modelling. Is this normal? The course I'm doing is probably the hardest course I've done at university(in Aust) to date.

Comment: Yes, they do match- you just forgot to minus the last term on your second part. That is the formula for variance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$Var(X-Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)-2Cov(X,Y)$. Only when X and Y are are uncorrelated when $Cov(X,Y)=0$ does the sum of the variances equal the variance of the difference.

Comment: O true I forgot about that. It's been a long time since I've done this so I forgot.